# Postgres SSL connection error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: postgresql, ssl

Postgresql version 10 on Ubuntu Bionic

Simple script to generate server certificate

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ] || [ -z $2 ];
    then
        echo "Usage: ./self-signed-server-certificates <curve> <signing-user>"
    exit 1
fi

CURVE=$1
SIGNING_USER=$2

openssl ecparam -name $CURVE -out private.pem -genkey
openssl req -new -sha256 -key private.pem -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey private.pem -out certificate.crt
chmod 400 private.pem
sudo chown postgres:postgres private.pem cp certificate.crt root.crt
```

Another simple script to generate client certificate

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ] || [ -z $2 ] || [ -z $3 ] || [ -z $4 ];
    then
        echo "Usage: ./self-signed-server-certificates <curve> <signing-user> <root certificate path> <server key path>"
    exit 1
fi

CURVE=$1
SIGNING_USER=$2
ROOT_CERTIFICATE=$3
SERVER_KEY=$4

openssl ecparam -name $CURVE -out private.pem -genkey
openssl req -new -sha256 -key private.pem -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in server.csr \
-CA $ROOT_CERTIFICATE -CAkey $SERVER_KEY -out public.crt -CAcreateserial
chmod 400 private.pem
sudo chown postgres:postgres private.pem
```

On DigitalOcean where I setup postgres, here is how I generate the server certificate

```
// assume we are in newly created droplet and created another super user(not root) called thor

sudo apt-get -y -qq update >> /dev/null && sudo apt-get -y -qq install postgresql postgresql-contrib >> /dev/null

cd ~ && mkdir experiment && touch experiment/gen_server_cert.sh

// paste the above generate server certificate code to it, chmod +x for it then run with

./gen_server_cert.sh brainpoolP512t1 thor

// interactive shell will come up to ask about info and blab blah, just enter blank line for all except the password challenge field, assume I entered "123!@#QWEqwe"
```

It successfully output 4 files, those are: `certificate.crt` `private.pem` `root.crt` and `server.crs`, then I copy them to `/etc/ssl/`

```
sudo cp private.pem /etc/ssl/private/postgresql_private.pem && sudo cp root.crt /etc/ssl/certs/postgresql_server.crt
```

Before I setup actually setup the SSL, I want to verify that I could successfully connect remotely from my local machine using `dbeaver`.

I start by creating a role for my postgres, create a testdb, change some config to allow connection from outside

```
sudo -u postgres -i
createuser -P -s -e thor // another interactive shell came up, enter password then done
// ctrl + d to get out from postgres
createdb ssl_test_db

sudo vim /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

// inside pg_hba.conf add this line
...
host ssl_test_db thor 0.0.0.0/0 md5
...

sudo vim /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf

// inside postgresql.conf uncomment the listen line and change it to listen to *

listen_addresses '*'

sudo service postgresql restart

// from dbeaver at my client machine, the setting for the connect are
Host: host_ip
Port: 5432
Database: ssl_test_db
User: thor
password: myverysecretpassword

// hit the button and yes it successfully connected
```

Then I went to change those config again to use ssl

```
// inside pg_hba.conf comment the line that just added and add this one
hostssl ssl_test_db thor 0.0.0.0/0 md5 clientcert=1

// inside postgresql.conf uncomment some line and change some line
ssl = on
ssl_ciphers = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK' # allowed SSL ciphers
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
ssl_ecdh_curve = 'brainpoolP512t1'
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/postgresql_server.crt'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/postgresql_private.pem'
ssl_ca_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/postgresql_server.crt'

// out to terminal
sudo service postgresql restart

// check for status
pg_lsclusters

// output
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

Then I open another terminal from local machine, sftp to it and get those necessary files to generate client certificate

```
sftp> cd experiment
sftp> get root.crt
sftp> get private.pem
```

Then at my local machine, create an empty folder, copy paste the generate client certificate script, chmod +x it then run it to generate those key and certificate

```
// assume at ~
// the files that get from server will also be at ~
mkdir experiment && cd experiment && vim gen_client_cert.sh // copy paste in
chmod +x ./gen_client_cert.sh

./gen_client_cert.sh brainpoolP512t1 thor ../root.crt ../private.pem
```

It will successfully generated 3 files, those are: `private.pem` `public.crt` and `server.scr`

Back to `dbeaver`, leave the above basic connection setting the same, go into SSL option and those setting are:

```
Use SSL - enabled
Root certificate: ~/root.crt
SSL certificate: ~/experiment/public.crt
SSL certificate key: ~/experiment/private.pem
```

When I hit the test connection button, the error occur and the message are:

```
SSL error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

The log from the server are:

```
LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: no shared cipher
```

Verification of the generated public certificate:

```
// back to terminal at local machine and current directory at ~
openssl verify -CAfile root.crt -purpose sslclient experiment/public.rt

// output
experiment/public.crt: OK
```

Comment: First things first: can you connect to your PostgreSQL using `psql` with `sslmode=require`? It is not clear to me which client generates "LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: no shared cipher", which means there is no possible handshake because of different versions (ex: one wants TLS1.2 only and the other does not about this version) between client and server. Especially because of "ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the comment. So I tried ``psql "sslmode=require host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dbname=ssl_test_db user=thor password=supersecretpass`` with env of ``PGSSLCERT=<location of crt>`` ``PGSSLKEY=<location of key>`` but it output me this ``psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "thor", database "ssl_test_db", SSL on``, It also output the same on the log, I am wondering if the client certificate actually being sent

Comment: did you find out what was causing this? I am experiencing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Either make sure you provide a valid SSL Certificate, or append the following in the URL field in the General tab:
?sslmode=disable

So, the url will be:
jdbc:postgresql://:5432/?sslmode=disable